# RXJS Subscription Chaining in Services

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, behaviorsubject

I have two services and a component. The component listens to service A which listens to service B. I am currently subscribing to service B in service A, running a filtering function, and then the filtering function is firing the observable in service A which the component listens to. Best practice would be to not subscribe to service B from service A and instead pass that observable up to the component that will be the only listener, but I can't figure out how to handle it properly.

**Current Setup:**

When user changes the type, the subscription in Service B fires which Service A listens to, then takes that data and creates a new array and fires the productsChanged subject which is listened to by the Component

```
Service A {
  productsChanged = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);

  types$: Subscription;

  private json: Product[] = ProductsJSON;
  private currentProducts: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private typeService: TypeService) {
    this.types$ = this.typeService.typeChanged.subscribe((type: Type) => {
      this.filterProducts(type);
    });
  }


  filterProducts(type: Type): void {
    this.currentProducts = [];

    // Do Some Filtering to Set the Current Products Based on Given Type
  }
}
```

When the person changes the product type it fires 'TypeChanged' which is listened to by Subject A to filter out products not matching the type

```
Service B {
  typeChanged = new BehaviorSubject<Type>(Defaults.TYPE);
  private chosenType: Type;

  constructor() {
    this.typeChanged.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((type) => {
      this.chosenType = type;
    });
  }

  setType(type: Type): void {
    this.chosenType = type;

    this.typeChanged.next(this.chosenType);
  }
}
```

Component subscribes in the HTML and just puts out a list of products

```
Component {
  products$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.products$ = this.productService.productsChanged.pipe(
      map((product) => {
        return product;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following changes in your service A to achieve this.

Your productsChanged should no longer be a BehaviorSubject, but instead it should be an unassigned property of type Observable, like this:

```
productsChanged: Observable<Product[]>;
```

Then in the constructor you do the following:

```
this.productsChanged = this.typeService.typeChanged.pipe(map((type: Type) => {
  return this.filterProducts(type);
}));
```

Lastly your filterProducts method need to return the filtered products, so something like this:

```
  filterProducts(type: Type): void {
    this.currentProducts = [];

    // Do Some Filtering to Set the Current Products Based on Given Type
    
    return filteredProducts;
  }
```

Comment: I ended up going with the other guys answer, though they were very similar and this was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: **Update: this answer actually worked better for my needs**

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things that could be changed.

1. If you aren't using the `chosenType` variable from Service B, it could save you from an additional subscription in it's constructor. Since you already have a variable `typeChanged` holding the current type, you could use it instead where you need the `chosenType` value.
2. In Service A, you could replace the `productsChanged` `BehaviorSubject` with a function that pipes to the `typeChanged` observable from Service B and use RxJS operators [`filter`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) and [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) along with RxJS function [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) to return an observable of type `Products[]`.

Service A (ProductService)

```js
{
  private json: Product[] = ProductsJSON;
  private currentProducts: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private typeService: TypeService) { }

  productsChanged(): Observable<Products[]> {
    this.currentProducts = [];
    return this.typeService.typeChanged.pipe(
      tap((type: Type) => this.currentProducts = /* something */ ),
      filter((type: Type) => /* filter `type` notifications based on certain conditions */ ),
      switchMap((type: Type) => 
        /* do something and return an observable of type `Products[]` using RxJS `of` function */
      )
    );
  }
}
```

You could pipe to it in the component like you do now.

Component

```js
{
  products$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.products$ = this.productService.productsChanged().pipe(  // <-- function instead of observable
      map((product) => {
        return product;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Figured it was something similar to this, just couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks!